# Change a text in my website footer (typo3)

Tags: php, html, frontend, typo3, content-management-system

So i have a landing page on my website. That landing page uses a template that was created not by me. On that site there is a footer with some text i need to delete. How do i do it? I cant find that text anywhere in the backend.

I even tried to use myphpadmin ad just search for that test snipped. It is nowhere to be found. So where does the frontend take that text from?

Comment: Is it wordpress, or what builder, what's the theme or template name?

Comment: If it's TYPO3 it can be in TypoScript. Did you check the Template module and searched there for the footer text?

Comment: it says in my title what builder i use.......Whats the name of the template? Its a individual template. What role has the name of the template in helping here?

Answer (score 0):

Text in the frontend can be originated from different options.

- the most common option: data from a record.
  primarily direct from table `tt_content`, second: a plugin (configured in a record from `tt_content`) shows records from other tables.
  The data can be from the same page, but also inherited from a page above. Or it is referenced from any other page with a record ID or page ID.
- it can come from a template

  - TypoScript template: it is defined by typoscript, which can be constant text or fetched from records or interfaces. (TypoScript can do nearly everything)
  - FLUID template: the layout of your site can show variables (filled from typoscript or viewhelpers) or even static text.
  - Marker template: not much used any more. But also: filled from typoscript or by static text.
- don't forget: language-files

---

You can search your whole server for files containing the text to replace. But that could find multiple occurrences (and probably only one is responsible) or none if the text is composed from multiple data fragments.

Better: identify the way the front page is generated and follow the data to the origin. This needs some understanding how TYPO3 works.

The final answer can come only from the last way, but needs access to the server which you should grant only to trusted persons.

Comment: "You can search your whole server for files containing the text to replace" an how do i do that? I did seach in phpmyadmin. The text isnt found there. Isnt that suppose to search the whole website?

Comment: you need to differ between the database and the filesystem. phpmyadmin will only search the database. Templates are stored as files in the filesystem. nowadays also typoscript is mostly stored in files (because of site-extensions, which hold nearly all configuration for a site). The site-extension is probably the place where specific site data is stored.

Comment: for a full search through all files you best need a shell access (SSH).

Comment: and how do i search the filesystem? I can only see like multimedia files stores in the filesystem.

Comment: as said: you need a Shell or at least (S)FTP. TYPO3 does not give you access to the whole filesystem for security reason. the folder `fileadmin/` is just for editor files. the extensions are stored in `typo3conf/ext/` and are protected.